# VBA logging in to website with 2 step login

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, authentication

as title says i am having an error at  **htdoc.all.verificationcode.Value = otp**

it says Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

i have spent an afternoon trying to find what is wrong with it and i really hope that you guys could help me out.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim htdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub login()
Dim username As Range
Dim password As Range
Dim otp As Range
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
MyURL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Set username = Range("B1")
Set password = Range("B2")
Set otp = Range("B3")
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.UserId.Value = username
HTMLDoc.all.password.Value = password
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

MyURL2 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
MyBrowser.silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL2
MyBrowser.Visible = True
myValue = InputBox("Enter OTP")
Range("B3").Value = myValue
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set htdoc = MyBrowser.document
htdoc.all.verificationcode.Value = otp
For Each MyHTML_Element In htdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "btnobj" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next


Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If

End Sub



HTML in the webpage for the form is
<input name="verficationcode" id="verficationcode" type="password" size="18" maxlength="16" autocomplete="off">
<input name="btnobj" class="inputbutton" id="submitButton" onclick="checkSubmit(this);" type="button" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Any reason you cannot use a private/public variable in the code that gets it's value from a standard [InputBox method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768%28v=office.11%29.aspx) or read the OTP from teh responseText of an XMLHTTP post?

Comment: i am new and i have not learnt that yet. thank you for your help jeeped!

Comment: No worries. Get started on some code and if you run into trouble, come back and edit your question to include your own effort (noting the line that is producing any errors together with the error message). I'll look forward to it! See [POST website form data and retrieve results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723571/post-website-form-data-and-retrieve-results/29724280#29724280) for a recent example.

Comment: i have done some codes but im stuck again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. That looks like a good start. You are going to a page, inputting some values and clicking <kbd>Submit></kbd>. You have not set `MyBrowser.visible` to *False* so I'm assuming that you can see this going on.

The first thing you need is to wait while MyBrowser loads the page after you `.click` <kbd>submit></kbd>. You will need to wait every time you go to a new page; My favorite is to put all of the waiting into a single line like this.

```
MyHTML_Element.Click
Do While (MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE): DoEvents: Loop
```

When you have that new page, you need to locate your OTP and store it in a variable. Look at the HTML behind the new page. You might see something like this:

```
<div id='One_Time_Password'>
     47665489_29751678
</div>
```

You can put this into a variable you have previously declared like this.

```
dim  myOTP as string
myOTP = MyBrowser.getElementsById("One_Time_Password").innerText
```

Now you have the password stored and you can do something with it.

Comment: my OTP is sent to my mobile and i type it into the inputbox prompt after main login page, which would put my OTP into the cell co can i set myOTP as the cell eg. set myOTP = range("B3").       and after i have done the waiting, where do i continue to filling in the OTP fields?

Comment: @JustinMichaelChia - I'm sorry but every web page uses different methods for passing along an OTP. You need to specify the actual URl of the web page so it can be examined for methods or edit your original question to include enough code that we can determine the method.

Comment: that might be a problem because i would need to log in to access the OTP page. i will see what i can get from the website

Comment: do you have an email that i can send the HTML code? maybe we can discuss something there @jeeped