# POST not working, while GET works fine (xmlhttp)

Tags: vba, excel, post

I'm writing an Excel macro to communicate with my API, and it seems I cannot send an request via POST, only GET is working.

My code:

```
Private Sub button1_Click()
   Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.xmlhttp, myurl As String
   myurl = "https://{my_url}"
   xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
   xmlhttp.send
   MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)
End Sub
```

Macro run returns:

**No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header**

When I modify the code, changing POST to GET:

```
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
```

It works fine, I get the response. How can I force excel to cooperate with POST method? Since my API for more advanced communication requires POST?

Comment: When you do a `POST` you send data. Are you submitting a form or something? Right now you are sending nothing. You would add the data on the `.send` line. GET returns data, like loading a page.

Comment: ^^this^^ see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723571/post-website-form-data-and-retrieve-results/29724280#29724280)

Comment: Does your API handle POST in the first place? If it does you can add debug output from it.

Comment: Hi, API handle POST. I have a working powershell script sending the same with POST to retrieve list of workflows I can start with my powershell.  @Ryan-Wildry  thanks for the suggestion, however it seems it doesn't matter if I try to send any parameters or not. It literally acts like it doesn't recognize word 'POST' (if I change it to "Whatever") I get the same error.

Comment: You have probably used wrong URI or made typo... HTTP 405 means that for that exact endpoint you are calling, POST is **not** allowed.

Comment: Yeah. I was SURE that's excel thing, that my request is not send.. And huh.. It was easier for me to:  google for like an hour, create this question, and after that I checked the logs from my API to see that's the responses from it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation there was nothing wrong with my VBA code. The response I got, was sent from my API. Thank you for comments, they helped me to resolve the issue by including XML body into xmlhttp.send command.